# safe usage of Python exec

Tags: python, security

We are taught that it is unsafe to use "exec statements" in python. But the blow code is vulnerable? The param "name" could be controlled by service users:

```
def welcome(name):
    name = name.replace("'", r"\047")
    exec "hello = 'welcome " + name + "!'"
    return hello
```

Assume string "name" could contains any characters.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Of what use is `exec` in that situation?

Comment: `name = "'; whatever_i_want; print 'bad news sucker"`

Comment: No, it isn't safe.  See @jonrsharpe's comment

Comment: @joelgoldstick Is it a safe use of "exec"? Is there a malicious input of string "name" could cause a security issue?

Comment: @jonrsharpe notice that the code does escape the single quote.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, but I don't think your payload could work. The character " ' " has been replaced to others.

Comment: @hikerell so it has. I'm not certain whether that would be sufficient for safety in all cases. But a better question might be: why do you think you need `exec` here? Just do `return 'welcome {}!'.format(name)`.

Comment: You can make it throw an exception, at least. Might be some parser bugs that are not known.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No special reason. I just prepare some kinds of tricks for CTF.

Comment: What does CTF mean?

Comment: @joelgoldstick The short of Capture The Flag, an interesting game for hackers or security students. You could learn more at [Google CTF](https://capturetheflag.withgoogle.com/) or  [DefCon CTF](https://legitbs.net/)

Comment: if the replacement were `r"\'"`, it'd be easily exploitable